# Angular 2 partial html injection with DomSanitizer

Tags: angular

the user input text as string :

`i try to learn html and this is a <h1>title</h1>`

i save the string to a class member
then i manipulate the string value and the result:

```
this.data = "<span style='color:red'>i try to learn html and this is a</span> <span style='color:green'><h1>title</h1></span>";
```

then i pass it to getData function:

**sanitizer is DomSanitizer**

```
getData(){
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.data);
}
```

and as a result the html h1 tag is being parsed to html element

**is there a way to treat a part of the string as a "pure string" so that his content wont be translated to a new html element? such as {{data}}**

this is the component html:

```
<div [ngStyle]=getStyles() [innerHTML]="getData()"></div>
```

Comment: So you'd like to have `span` elements rendered as html but not h1 ones?

Comment: @Supamiu yes exacly

Comment: Binding to a function is a very bad idea. `innerHTML` will be updated every time change detection is run. Instead assign the result of `getData` to a field and bind to this field instead.

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the "pure string" part?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the expected behavior is to treat is as a string value that will not be parsed to html element:
this will be color red : "i try to learn html and this is a"
and this will be color green : "<h1>title</h1>"

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the title string to another variable and call it inside the `this.data` variable

```
this.title = "<h1>title</h1>";
this.data = `<span style='color:red'>i try to learn html and this is a</span> <span style='color:green'> ${this.title} </span>`;
```

in html just call the `data` variable.

```
<div [ngStyle]="getStyles()" [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

Comment: in this example the value of this.title is rendered as html element and not as text  so it doesn't work :(